# Correlation in Panel Data with different number of observation for individuals

Tags: r, correlation, cross-correlation, panel-data

I have the following panel data with some individuals having more observations than the others.

```
id <- c("John","John","John","John","John",
        "Mike","Mike","Mike","Mike", 
        "Andrea","Andrea","Andrea","Andrea","Andrea","Andrea","Andrea")
time <- c(1:5, 1:4, 1:7)
observation <- c(rnorm(1:5), rnorm(1:4), rnorm(1:7))

paneldata <- data.frame(id, time, observation)
```

I want to calculate the correlation for the observations among the individuals. R should ignore the missing observations, e.g.

Correlation between Mike and John: only time 1 to 4 should be considered

Correlation between John and Andrea: only time 1 to 5  etc.

What's the best way to achieve these results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to spread your data set into a wide format and then just run `cor` over the whole data set (while removing `time`) and specifying `"pairwise.complete.obs"` within the `cor` function so it will compare only relative observations. I would also suggest you will use a `set.seed` when creating a random data set. These results will match `set.seed(123)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
paneldata %>%
  spread(id, observation) %>%
  select(-time) %>%
  cor(., use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
#            Andrea       John       Mike
# Andrea  1.0000000  0.1288513 -0.3770482
# John    0.1288513  1.0000000 -0.8471950
# Mike   -0.3770482 -0.8471950  1.0000000
```

---

Just in order for you to easier understand how the wide data set looks like before running `cor`, here is an illustration on your dat set

```
#      Andrea        John       Mike
# 1 -0.4456620 -0.56047565  1.7150650
# 2  1.2240818 -0.23017749  0.4609162
# 3  0.3598138  1.55870831 -1.2650612
# 4  0.4007715  0.07050839 -0.6868529
# 5  0.1106827  0.12928774         NA
# 6 -0.5558411          NA         NA
# 7  1.7869131          NA         NA
```

---

As pointed out by @akrun in comments, you can achieve a similar result using `reshape2::acast` which will also save you the effort of removing the `time` column because it will convert it into row names

```
library(reshape2)
cor(acast(paneldata, time ~ id, value.var = 'observation'), use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')
#            Andrea       John       Mike
# Andrea  1.0000000  0.1288513 -0.3770482
# John    0.1288513  1.0000000 -0.8471950
# Mike   -0.3770482 -0.8471950  1.0000000
```

Comment: I tried to use your code on big panel data set (1.1 mil observations) and it is very slow. Do you have any recommendation how to calculate correlations quicker?